# Poisson Distribution question solving

Tags: poisson-distribution

I'm stuck solving a Poisson distribution question, not entirely sure how I go about actually calculating the answer

So a call centre receives telephone calls at a rate of 12 per hour, the clerk working at the centre wants to go for a break. How long must her coffee break be if she is to have a  50/50 chance of not missing a call?

So I'm pretty confident about my reasoning for this;

$$P(N(t) = 0) = e^{-12t} \frac{(12t)^0}{0!} \leq 0.5$$

However i'm clueless how to actually solve this? Do I have to rearrange for $t$? and how do I use the 0.5 probability in this question?

Comment: You already have the equation that you must solve! Can you solve it? Hint: take the log of both sides!

Comment: $t = -\frac{\ln (0.5)}{12}$

Comment: I think you must have the inequality to the other side. Since you want that the probability is at least 0.5, I guess?

Comment: @shashi trying that, getting a unexpectedly small number. looking at it i think i was ignoring the 0.5 probability being separate.. (thanks for the edit as well) cheers